# Accessing state using a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have started learning React, and decided to create my first app similar to online food ordering cart.

My problem started with accessing the state of the current number of the particular dish in the shopping cart ( if I want to order 2 pizzas it would show '2x Pizza' in the shopping cart ).

As I don't really want to use if method as it would make my code not really professional, I wanted to ask you if do you know how to sort out my problem.

What I've got for the moment is that part of the code:

```
this.state = {
  values: {
   pizza:0
  }
 }


<div className="item" onClick={(e) => this.addItem(e)} itemprice={1250} foodtype="values.pizza"><p className="itemDesc">Pizza</p></div>

addItem(e) {
   let foodType = clickObj.getAttribute("foodtype"); // values.pizza

    this.setState({
        [foodType]: [foodType] + 1
    });
}
```

I expected to increase this.state.value.pizza by 1 on each click of the button. I have to specify the variable with an attribute name because there would be quite a few of positions to order and I want to keep my code as tidy as I can.

Unfortunately, I can access the state but the value of that state is not being changed after click. (checked using console.log)

Comment: Isn't it because you are not updating the state right? it should be something like `this.setState({ values: { ...this.state.values, [foodType]:  this.state.values[foodType] + 1  });` obviously there are many ways to make it preetier...

Comment: That done the work, thanks a lot it was really helpful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use previous state value to increment, you can use the following code.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({[foodType]: prevState[foodType] + 1}))
```

Also you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en extention for chrome which will give you details about the state and other values.

Hope that answers your question.